# How to start a genymotion device that is already on?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion

This is what I see in my genymotion prompt(genymotion device manager)

[image]

What I usually do to start my GenyMotion virtual device is start. However start is disabled because the device is already on apparently. Is there another way I can get to this device?

Comment: How did this happened? Did you already launched the device and it crashed? Did you try to launch it through the Genymotion app (not the plugin).

Comment: I launched the virtual device manager through the genymotion icon in eclipse

Comment: Ok but your problem is still not clear. If you started the device you don't need to start it again. Does device is still running? If no how has it been shutdown? Please provide more details about the current situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir. in Intllij IDEA or Andorid Studio you dont need to use that. just set Target Device in Edit Configuration setting to USB Device and after run project thats show Genymotion virtual devices.

Comment: Like Is there still I way i can get to the device, so i can run other applications, perform other operations?

Answer (score -1):

You can go to platform-tools inside your android-sdk folder in Terminal/Shell and type the following command:

```
adb reboot
```

It will restart the device.